# unbind socket connection C#/python

Tags: c#, python, sockets

What I have:

- I have two socket client programs written in C#.
- I have one socket server program (not written by me but it works) in Python.

The problem:

The first c# socket client I wrote works fine and can communicate with the python server client. I can send data over with no issue.  However I wanted to rewrite the code to make it more object oriented, so I made the second program which is the same as the first in terms of what is done.

The issue is the second one won't connect, saying this:

> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An attempt was made to access a socket in a forbidden way by its access permissions.

I googled this and I have come to the realization that the connection from the first connection hasn't been completely unbound.

When I did a `netstat -a`, I actually saw the connection and it said TIME_WAIT at the end.

The question is, how do I unbind it?  Is it on the C#/client side?

FYI I have already tried closing/disconnecting/shutting down the socket and none of that worked.  I also put in this command

```
connection.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
```

upon instantiation of the socket connection but that did not work either.

Would I have to do something on the server side to unbind the connection?

Comment: Your client programs should not be binding to a specific port—are you sure you're not confusing the client with the server?

Answer (score 0):

I know you said you already calling close or disconnect.

But are you reinitializing the socket variable.

eg: connection = new System.Net.Sockets.Socket(...

If you are using an older version of .Net you may also have to call Dispose() after call Close().

eg:

```
connection.Close();
connection.Dispose();
connection = new System.Net.Sockets.Socket(...
```

Be sure to always work with sockets within try statements as any calls to send and receive data or close the socket could result it an error at which stage, you should log the error and call Close() and then if applicable Dispose() on the socket instance to clear the resources. Once this has been done, you can then reinitialize a new instance of the socket to attempt a new connection to the server.